# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Hi I'm using TensorFlow on Linux with python 3.8.5, and I have upgraded the TensorFlow. But when I run the following code in the TensorFlow virtual environment

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def get_dataset(training=True):
    mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
    #some code
    return something
```

It shows that

```
File "intro_keras.py", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "/TensorFlow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "/TensorFlow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager'
```

How can I get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the `tensorflow` module?

Comment: This error might be tensorflow not installed properly. Uninstall the existing Tensorflow and install the new Tensorflow version using `!pip install tensorflow`. Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to run the program?
If I use replit.com, I see this:
[Failed to install](https://storage.googleapis.com/replit/images/1616001139210_3e1e51638d3b33f401782cc308cdd2dd.png)